# Binding in C# and XAML error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have the following code which I should put a random number in the `content` of a button.But rather everytime the content of the button is the same value `0`-
This is part of my `C#` code-

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }
        public int RandomNumber { get; set; }
        public int GenerateRandomNumber(int min, int max)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            return random.Next(5,40);
        }

  private void ButtonNo3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int ans = 0;
        Button obj = (Button)sender;
        var selectedButton = obj.Content.ToString(); 
        //some more code
    }
```

This is part of my `XAML` code in which my button should have a random number in its content-

```
            <Button 
            x:Name="Button3"
            Content="{Binding Path=RandomNumber}"                           
            Click="ButtonNo3"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="0,118,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Height="37" 
            Width="47"/>
```

SO my question is why is the `Content` of the `Button3` always `0` when it should be random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should do the trick

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private int __RandomNumber;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }
    public int RandomNumber 
    { 
        get{return _RandomNumber} 
        set
        {
            if (_RandomNumber != value){
              _RandomNumber = value;
              this.OnPropertyChanged("RandomNumber");//needed for binding
            }
        }; 
    }
    public int GenerateRandomNumber(int min, int max)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        RandomNumber = random.Next(5,40); //changed this line, do the assign
        return RandomNumber;
    }

    private void ButtonNo3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int ans = 0;
        Button obj = (Button)sender;
        var selectedButton = obj.Content.ToString(); 
        //some more code
        GenerateRandomNumber(0,0);  //added : generate a random number
    }
```

There are multiple issues that i solved with this code.
You are never generating a random number, not assigning it either.
You are not implementing inotifypropertychanged so even if you were the generate a new number it would not be picked up by the binding. The code above is not tested, it may have still some issues, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: You should probably avoid creating a new instance of the `Random` class per method call, especially if the generation of a "random" number has the potential of being called very quickly. (The default `Random` constructor is seeded by the system clock, and could result in the same "random" number.) A better solution would be to make a class level instance, and call the `Next(lower, max)` method. For more information [here's the MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.random.aspx). Look at the `Remarks` section for information on the default constructor issue.

Comment: Missing the implementation for INotifyPropertyChanged. I added it.

Comment: @Cameron I have many buttons and all of them get the same random value.I think you were warning me of the same but I am not able to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You are not calling the GenerateRandomNumber function anywhere (at least not in the code shown), so the RandomNumber property will always have the default value 0.

Comment: More on that, he is not setting `RandomNumber` to the value of the return from `GenerateRandomNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated you're not calling the GenerateRandomNumber method any where. You need to set the content property of the button to the value returned by the random number method.

To get a different value every time put this code before you set your selectedButton variable in the click event.

```
obj.Content = GenerateRandomNumber(5,40);
var selectedButton = obj.Content;
```

On another note. The parameters for your GenerateRandomNumber method are useless. You're not using them.you should be doing this:

```
private int GenerateRandonNumber( int min, int max ) {
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.Next( min, max );
}
```